# Polygon is created far away the specified position, LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I've been looking for solutions in google with no success, I'm creating a small library (just a wrapper) for Box2D in LibGDX and I'm drawing a texture for each body, taking as base the Body.getPosition() vector, however, I see polygon's getPosition() is different respect to CircleShapes and the walls (which were created with setAsBox() method).

Here's an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzooG.png

The red points are the center of mass, the cyan circles are the geometric center (right?) given by body.getPosition(), as you can see I can adapt the texture to the body in terms of position, rotation and scale but this does not happen with polygons (except the ones made with setAsBox()).

Basically, what I want is to get the cyan circle in the AABB centre of the regular polygons. here's a runnable example:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

Tabox2D t;
float w ,h;
@Override
public void create () {
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    t = Tabox2D.getInstance();
    t.debug = true;

    t.newBall("d", 100, 200, 25);// Ball.
    t.newBox("s", 10, 10, w - 20, 50);// Floor.
    t.newHeptagon("d", new Vector2(200, 200), 40);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    t.update(0);// Don't move anything just to see the cyan circle.
    t.draw();
}
}
```

Tabox2D class is here: https://github.com/tavuntu/tabox2d

NOTE: this was tested with the last version of Android Studio and LibGDX.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think I solved this maybe in an inelegant way. What I did was:

1. Create the polygons points around the origin
2. Get AABB center of polygon and centroid (not necessarily the same)
3. Translate points to make AABB center the shape center, so the image can be drawn respect to this and not the center of mass.

The code needs a lot of cleaning but it seems to work just well, updated code in github repo, thanks!

The change was basically translate points from the original centroid to AABB center:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pts.length - 1; i += 2) {
        pts[i] -= aabbCenter.x;
        pts[i + 1] -= aabbCenter.y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are positioning the shapes on the centre point, instead of the body. The centre of the shapes should be 0,0, not center.x,y. Fixture positions are relative to the body.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was rendering the sprites respecting to Body.getWorldCenter(), but the problem is, getPosition() and getWorldCenter() are not neccessarily the same, I get this when using the center of mass: http://s22.postimg.org/fz8rbd5m9/ss2.png as you can see these two centers are in the same point when the AABB of the polygon is a square, otherwise they don't match :(

Comment: I found a way to get the vertices of the PolygonShape in the polygons but these seem to be inmutable and keep the initial values.

Comment: As I said, you are generating the points for the vertices incorrectly. You offset the shape from bodies centre, so the fixtures are offset and your sprites end up in wrong place

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully familiarized with LibGDX/Box2D API, I'll check out some manuals and see how to fix this. In the meantime, this Library (just a class) is in my repo as an early beta versión: https://github.com/tavuntu/tabox2d I change the line defPoly.position.set(center.x, center.y); to defPoly.position.set(0, 0); but  I'm still figuring out how to fix that. Thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Providing a runnable example with the lib would go a long way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, post edited with example, not sure if I should put a link to a project's zip so I left the main (core) class and a link to the library.